# Filtering array of objects with a search term gets "TypeError: includes is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I don't seem to understand JavaScript enough to get why this doesn't work:

```
let sample = [
                        {
                            "id":90,
                            "name":"Fort McMurray Airport",
                            "city":"Fort Mcmurray",
                        },
                        {
                            "id":273,
                            "name":"Murtala Muhammed International Airport",
                            "city":"Lagos",
                        },
                        {
                            "id":1227,
                            "name":"San Javier Airport",
                            "city":"Murcia"
                        },
                        {
                            "id":1235,
                            "name":"Alcantarilla Air Base",
                            "city":"Murcia",
                        },
                        {
                            "id":1275,
                            "name":"Muret-Lherm Airport",
                            "city":"La Rochelle",
                        },
                    ]

                    let airports = sample.filter(
                        function(obje) {
                            return Object.keys(obje).some(
                                function(key) {
                                    return obje[key].includes("Murc");
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    );
```

I keep getting a "TypeError: obje[key].includes is not a function"
BTW, this is content from an axios call
Thanks in advance.

I solved it like so:

```
let query = "Murc";
let new_airports = sample.filter(sample => (sample.name.includes(query) || sample.city.includes(query) ) );
```

I was letting the code fly over my head. However, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: obje[key].includes is not a function

This error caused by `id` types

in your sample data, `id` is `Number` but `includes()` is for `string` only.

```js
let sample = [{
    "id": 90,
    "name": "Fort McMurray Airport",
    "city": "Fort Mcmurray",
  },
  {
    "id": 273,
    "name": "Murtala Muhammed International Airport",
    "city": "Lagos",
  },
  {
    "id": 1227,
    "name": "San Javier Airport",
    "city": "Murcia"
  },
  {
    "id": 1235,
    "name": "Alcantarilla Air Base",
    "city": "Murcia",
  },
  {
    "id": 1275,
    "name": "Muret-Lherm Airport",
    "city": "La Rochelle",
  },
]


const res = sample.filter((item, index) => {
  return Object.keys(item).some((key) => {
    return item[key].toString().includes('Murc')
  });
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a better solution than my half-baked edit. All I have to do is add .toLowerCase() to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: @SamuelAnyaele or you can reduce above code to this `sample.filter(val=>Object.keys(val).some(key=>val[key].toString().includes("Murc")))`

Answer (score 0):

includes might not work for a string, try indexOf instead.
Do something like this : return obje[key].indexOf("Murc") > -1;